# unable to connect mysql database from remote ubuntu tomcat server in android

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, remote-server

i have developed one java application.here i have to run the java class on my local server means right click on project ---run as--->java application.

so i have getting the output.

But i wish to upload this java app to my remote tomcat server.so i have export my project as war file.after i have to unzip the war file in remote tomcat server. now i have to run these project.

The java code is given below:

```
 public class Fetch {
 public String customerData(){
 String customerInfo = "";
 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/android","androiduser","AN124@7#7");
 //Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
 PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers");
 ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
 while(result.next()){
  customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("login") + "&" + result.getString("password") + "&"+result.getString("firstname") + "&"+result.getString("email");
 //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
  }
 }
catch(Exception exc){
System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}
return customerInfo;
}
}
```

How can i run these Fetch.java class on my remote tomcat server.please help me.how can i get the retrieve data.

Comment: To add on the answers here you need to have the jdbc initialization code set in the init method of the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a web server that implements Servlet and JSP specification.

So it is not for running normal java app like we do from command prompt using `javac` and `java` commands.

You need a web app to run your file from a servlet. So first you will need to learn about servlets.[See the Servlets Wiki page on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using hard-coded values for the server address, username and password. These are things that should be configured as a part of the Tomcat server configuration. I don't have much experience with Tomcat myself but take a look at this article to hopefully get you on the right path.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html